# How to use try catch in visual studio c++?

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, fortify

```
#include <windows.h>

int csOpsPrintDataInitialized = 0;

void ObtainOpsPrintDataCritSect()
{
    CreateCriticalSectionAsNeccessary();

    EnterCriticalSection(&csOpsPrintData);
} // Hp fortify in visual studio 2013 reporting issue: Exception handling.
```

but on using try catch it is still reporting same issue.

```
void ObtainOpsPrintDataCritSect_sol()]
{
    try
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&csOpsPrintData);
    }
    catch(char *msg)
    {
    }
}
```

Hp fortify recommendation: This problem can be avoided in two ways:

- Wrap calls to EnterCriticalSection() in a try/catch block.
- Call the function InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount() instead of InitializeCriticalSection(). This pre-allocates the event that EnterCriticalSection() uses rather than forcing EnterCriticalSection() to allocate the event.

Comment: Are you sure it says `try/catch` ? I'd expect `__try/__catch`. The two are similar in intent, but `try` is C++, `__try` is Windows, and `EnterCriticalSection` is also Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a false positive you should ignore the recommendation in fortify because the documentation on `EnterCriticalSection` on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms682608(v=vs.85).aspx) states :

> Do not handle a possible deadlock exception; instead, debug the
>   application.